# How to install pylibfreenect in python?

Tags: python, kinect, libfreenect2

Im trying to install `pylibfreenect` in Pycharm but its giving me this error message:

```
 Collecting pylibfreenect2
  Using cached pylibfreenect2-0.1.4.tar.gz (125 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Steffen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wbvm76g8\pylibfreenect2_46804a2858bc48829d3d48cfaa63fcde\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
          raise OSError("{}: is not found".format(libfreenect2_configh_path))
      OSError: /usr/local/include\libfreenect2\config.h: is not found
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I looked up the GitHub forum https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect but I dont know how to install `libfreenect` from there.
I know it cannot find config.h because the website is down. How can I still install it?
If possible detailed instructions please.

Answer (score 0):

To intall `libfreenect2` on Windows, you need to install few dependencies `libusb`, `TurboJPEG`, `GLFW`.
And then you need to clone `libfreenect2` repo to build using `make && make install` command. This will install `libfreenect2` on your machine.

Same steps are for MacOS.

See this readme for detailed steps - https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/README.md